# Chrome onbeforeunload AJAX Requests Cancelled

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, browser, onbeforeunload

I had a questions regarding the onbeforeunload event that can be triggered when a user leaves a page. I was looking through this site and noticed that people were having issues completing AJAX requests when this event hit in Chrome. I have also seen the solution where the ajax call should be set to be synchronous rather than asynchronous. That's not quite my problem. My problem is that I can already have generated the ajax request (before the user tries to leave the page) in Chrome, and if the user tries to leave the page before the client gets the reply, the dialog will come up, the user can choose to not leave the page, but all AJAX functionality is dropped (client never gets the reply). Is there a way around this in Chrome? This seems to have been a bug for a long time now (maybe not since its been so long there must be a reason for it).

Also, if there is an alternative to using this method in with Chrome then please let me know. Thank you.